# Editing multiple base64 strings in python

Tags: python, json, list, selenium-webdriver, base64

Im using selenium to navigate to a website with some furniture images. Only thing is, the images are in base64. not downloadable .jpg files.

Im using this to write a json file with the images all bunched up together.

```
def write_urlList(url_list):
    with open("base64imgLinks.json", "w") as fp:
        json.dump(url_list, fp)
        print("URL list done.")

imageTags = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//img[contains(@id, '__image8-_')]")
imageLinks = [img.get_attribute('src') for img in imageTags]

write_urlList(imageLinks)
```

This gives me a long file with all the images bunched up. Maybe changing this up would be a solution in and of itself?

Start of the file looks like `["data:image/png;base64 ,  iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABL.....`

and between the images: `...FTkSuQmCC", "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA.....`

I'm guessing my best bet is to edit this file to remove the start of it and the middles of the images and seperate them with some unique symbols that i can later use when comverting them to pngs?

This is my first python project, so i'm a little but out of my depth :p
It's ambitius i know, but i have some general understanding of code. Though, still havent understood this :p

I've tried using this that i found elsewhere on stackexchange but cant get it to do anything to the inputs i give it. Be it .json or .txt(this case its .txt)

```
data = []
with open("Links.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()

print(len(data))

 # ^this returns 0 every time.
images = [w.replace('\n', '').replace('data:image/png;base64', '').replace('["','') for w in data]
for index, base64string in enumerate(images):

  test = base64string.encode()

  with open("image_{0}.png".format(index), "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(base64.decodebytes(test))
```

Moreover, if theres a different way entierly of going about the base64 problem that would be nice.

Comment: If `len(data)` is zero every time, you're not going to get anywhere.  You need to find out why reading the file is failing.  Does `Links.txt` start with a blank line?

Comment: As stated in the question the textfile starts with ```["data:image/png;base64 ,  iVBORw0KGgoAAAA....```

Comment: Then I suggest you have more than one `Links.txt` file, and you're opening the wrong one.  And that one is empty.

Comment: In other words, make a [mcve] (<- *please read the link*) that can be copied and executed *without changes* to reproduce the issue.  Include a *small* input file sample that shows the issue.

Comment: It seems i was not accesing the .txt file properly. Now that i am though, the code thats supposed to get the 4 base64 images and make it into for images isnt working at all. I'll probably need a different approach..